# Laravel 4 upload image form

Tags: php, frameworks, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to make a form that allows uploading a file and store it in the public/upload folder of the application.

my form is:

```
<form action="/image/save" method="post">
<input name="image" type="file" />
<input type="submit" value="Save"/>
</form>
```

and the controller:

```
public function save(){
$file = Input::file('image');
$destinationPath = 'upload/';
$filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
Input::file('image')->move($destinationPath, $filename);
```

But when I run it I get the following error:
Call to a member function `getClientOriginalName()` on a non-object

Comment: You're using $file->getClientOriginalName(). It has nothing to do with $file

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You need to have a [file input](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Html/FormBuilder.php#L118) enabled on a form. ([Doc](http://laravel.com/docs/html#file-input))

In Laravel, you can use:

```
Form::open('image/save', array('files'=> true))
```

or

```
<form action="/images/save" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Otherwise all you are receiving from the file input is the file name as a string.

Comment: but I do not understand where you have to write this?

Comment: In your view instead of the HTML <form> tag.

Comment: Question: where did you find in the documentation the `'files'=>true` ? I searched under Forms & Input sections but I found nothing..

Comment: @Valentin this can be found within the FormBuilder inside of Illuminate/Html https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Html/FormBuilder.php#L118

This is also listed in the http://laravel.com/docs/html#file-input documentation under opening a form.

Comment: For those who do not want to use laravel's Form Helper, adding `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute to your form tag will be enough.

Answer (score 11):

If you not use Blade for generate your form like this

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => 'foo/bar', 'files' => true)) }}
```

Just add this parameter to your form tag

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

Comment: `'files' => true` , that's what I was searching for.

Answer (score 8):

I also faced the same problem with one of my forms, the problem was the form wasn't defined with the option, `'files' => true` , which tells the Laravel4 form helper to define a form with `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Here is what i did:

Define the following array in your controller and pass it to your view ,

```
$form_options = array (
    'url' => 'path/to/defined/route',
    'class'  => 'form-horizontal',
    'name'   => 'newUser',
    'files'  => true
);
```

In your view, define your form as follows:

```
{{ Form::open( $form_options ) }}
```

That will define your form with `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Comment: I forgot to say files; I was having file! Stupid me

Answer (score 2):

You have to get the filename as follows:

```
//Blade form
{{ Form::open_for_files('/image/save') }}
{{ Form::file('image') }}
{{ Form::close() }}

//get imagename
$filename = Input::file('image.name');
```

Good luck! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can just add the field `'files'=> true` in your `array()` if you use Laravel form style something like

```
{{ Form::open(array('url'=>'/images/save','role'=>'form','files'=> true)) }}
```

otherwise you can use the html form tag something like

```
<form action="/images/save" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Hope this will help you.