# Uploaded file(picture) won't be saved within a specific folder

Tags: mysql, laravel, image

I got a problem with one of the functionalities of my Laravel project.
The thing is, I have a form with multiple inputs and one them is a type file, when the form is submitted the file needs to be saved into a specific path (`\MultiAuth\public\assets\upload\category`) and the request data needs to be stored into the database.

I can store the data into the database, however the uploaded file won't be added to the folder.

[This is the database image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhtzf.png)

I will add some code:

**Controller:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\category;

class CategoryController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
        return view('Admin.category.index');
    }
    public function add()
    {
        return view('Admin.category.add');
    }
    public function insert(Request $request)
    {
        $category = new Category();
        if($request->hasFile('image'))
        {
           $file = $request->file('image');
           $ext = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
           $filename = time().'.'.$ext;
           $file->move('assets/upload/category/',$filename);
           $category ->image = $filename;
            
        }
        $category->name =$request->input('name');
        $category->slug =$request->input('slug');
        $category->description =$request->input('description');
        $category->status =$request->input('status') == TRUE ? '1':'0';
        $category->popular =$request->input('popular') == TRUE ? '1':'0';
        $category->image =$request ->input('image');
        $category->meta_title =$request->input('meta_title');
        $category->meta_keywords =$request->input('meta_keywords');
        $category->meta_descrip =$request->input('meta_descrip');
        $category->save();
        return redirect('/admin/home')->with('status',"categary added successfully ");

        

    }
}
```

**View:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Blue Bird Industries ') }}</title>

    <!-- Fonts -->
      <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/42d5adcbca.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!-- Material Icons -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons+Round" rel="stylesheet">
  
    {{--  --}}
    <link href="{{ asset('admin/css/material-dashboard.css?v=3.1.0') }}" rel="stylesheet">

    
</head>
<body >
  <main class="main-content position-relative max-height-vh-100 h-100 border-radius-lg ">
    <!-- Navbar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-main navbar-expand-lg px-0 mx-4 shadow-none border-radius-xl" id="navbarBlur" data-scroll="true">
    @include('layouts/inc/adminnav')
  </nav>

  @include('layouts/inc/sidebar')
  <div class="container py-4">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-header">
            <h1 class="text-center">Add Category</h1>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <form action="{{ url('insert-category') }}" method="POST">
              @csrf
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name">Name:</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Enter the category name" required>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="slug">Slug:</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="slug" id="slug" placeholder="Enter the category slug" required>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="description">Description:</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" name="description" id="description" rows="3" placeholder="Enter the category description" required></textarea>
              </div>
              <div class="form-check">
                <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="status" id="status">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="status">Status</label>
              </div>
              <div class="form-check">
                <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="popular" id="popular">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="popular">Popular</label>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="image">Image:</label>
                <input type="file" name="image" id="image" class="form-control-file">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="meta_title">Meta Title:</label>
                <input type="text" name="meta_title" id="meta_title" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter the meta title">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="meta_keywords">Meta Keywords:</label>
                <input type="text" name="meta_keywords" id="meta_keywords" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter the meta keywords">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="meta_descrip">Meta Description:</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" name="meta_descrip" id="meta_description" rows="3" placeholder="Enter the meta description"></textarea>
              </div>
              
              <div class="text-center">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Submit</button>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  </main>
  <footer class="footer py-4  ">
    <div class="container-fluid">
     
       @include('layouts/inc/adminfooter')
<footer>

     <script src="{{ asset('admin/js/popper.min.js') }}"></script>
       <script src="{{ asset('admin/js/perfect-scrollbar.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('admin/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('admin/js/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>
   
</body>
</html>
```

**Migration file:**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

return new class extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     */
    public function up(): void
    {
        Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('slug');
            $table->longText('description');
            $table->tinyInteger('status')->default('0');
            $table->tinyInteger('popular')->default('0');
            $table->string('image');
            $table->string('meta_title');
            $table->string('meta_descrip');
            $table->string('meta_keywords');
            $table->timestamps();

        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     */
    public function down(): void
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('categories');
    }
};
```

Did someone encounter the same problem?

Comment: Check if the path is wrong, change the actual path with: `$file->move(public_path('\assets\upload\category\'),$filename);`. public_path, makes reference to the public folder

Comment: this is also not working  are you have any other solution

Comment: There are many examples here, all of them show you need to include `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your form: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16635700/laravel-4-upload-image-form, https://stackoverflow.com/q/51680805/6089612, https://stackoverflow.com/q/62761342/6089612, https://stackoverflow.com/q/73673831/6089612, https://stackoverflow.com/q/65937433/6089612, ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel 4 upload image form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16635700/laravel-4-upload-image-form)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late reply, I was busy.

I did took a look into your code (not in detail), a solution for what you have is:

**Controller:**

```
public function insert(Request $request)
{
    $category = new Category();
    $filename = null; ***-> instantiate a local variable***
    if($request->hasFile('image'))
    {
       /* 
          *$request->image* is the same as $request->file('image'), use whatever you 
          like
       */
       $file = $request->image;
       $ext = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
       $filename = time().'.'.$ext;
       $file->move('assets/upload/category/',$filename);
    }

    $category->name =$request->input('name');
    $category->slug =$request->input('slug');
    $category->description =$request->input('description');
    $category->status =$request->input('status') == TRUE ? '1':'0';
    $category->popular =$request->input('popular') == TRUE ? '1':'0';
    $category->image =$filename; ***-> name of the file***
    $category->meta_title =$request->input('meta_title');
    $category->meta_keywords =$request->input('meta_keywords');
    $category->meta_descrip =$request->input('meta_descrip');

    $category->save();
    return redirect('/admin/home')->with('status',"categary added successfully ");

}
```

**View:**

```
      <div class="card-body">
        <form action="{{ url('insert-category') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          @csrf
```

just added `enctype="multipart/form-data"`, this line  allows entire files to be included in the data. then you can manage it and save it in the folder.

you can store data too using Storage, check out the documentation:
https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/filesystem

Cheers, if you have any doubt just ask